# Calendar days and Time into UIDatePicker with Inline style show only in English

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uidatepicker

I have made a view with UIDatePicker in Preferred Style "Inline". I need show this calendar in Spanish, so I added Locale lines:

```
[_pickerCalendar setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"]];
_pickerCalendar.calendar.locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"es"];
```

With this, I could see that general DatePicker translated correctly but calendar and time label show English yet (see image)

[image]

I believed that it could be a iOS bug, but when I saw iOS native calendar it show Spanish correctly (see image)

[image]

I can't find which property  is the correct to change language. Into Settings - General - Language and Region I hace this information:

- Region: Mexico
- Calendar: Gregorian
- Preferred Language: Spanish

Aditional info:

- iOS 14.5 (Simulator) and iOS 14.6 (Device)
- Xcode 12.5
- Language: Objective-C

Thanks for your help because I really need it.

UPDATE:

I implemented UIDatePicker in Swift with this code:

```
calendarPicker.locale = Locale(identifier: "es-MX")
calendarPicker.calendar.locale = Locale(identifier: "es-MX")
```

and the result was days into calendar already shows in Spanish but the label "Time" shows in English yet and not in Spanish. You can see it in the image:

[image]

Comment: This code works as expected for me on **iOS 14.6** when running from **Xcode 12.5**. Can you try and confirm? Maybe this is an issue that was addressed in **iOS 14.6**?

Comment: FWIW, it still shows **Time** instead of **Hora**. See https://imgur.com/BYgsKN0

Comment: @TarunTyagi I tested in my device with iOS 14.6 and it happens the same. I updated my post with this info

Comment: BTW I tried this in a project with Swift. I'm not sure if `NSLocale` vs `Locale` would cause this issue. Can you try with Swift to rule that out?

Comment: @TarunTyagi ok, I have the behavior as you said, Time shows instead Hora, but yes, it is a Objective-C. I will update my question.

Comment: What language shown in system UIImagePicker camera? does it work fine?

Comment: Did you found any way to localize this "Time" label? Or maybe hide it or something?